# Что за файлы появились в директории сайта?

Tags: php, html

называется DF8C1518EBEF74FA1E28A200FD3BBE0A.txt

в файле

ae78f642309034c0b0cbb91f3ab7dc7eda30c00b
comodoca.com

Что это такое? Взлом? Как победить если взлом?

Comment: Панель хостинга cPanel? Хостинг какой?

Comment: до cPanel best-hoster.ru

Comment: Знакомая история. Что-то сейчас хостер непонятное творит

Comment: @tutankhamun хостер вроде бы сказал что файлы cPanel не обращать внимания...

Comment: Угу. Только файлы множатся как кролики :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В файле явно используется ссылка на домен. Он имеет отношение к вашему сайту? Нет. Это ссылка формируется бесплатным VPN клиентом от Comodo, если не ошибаюсь. Так же это могут быть какие-то иные сервисы от Comodo, например, SSL анализатор.
Пользовались чем-то таким?
Если нет, то скорее всего, взлом и кто-то маскируется под эти сервисы.

Comment: рано паниковать начал, хостинг просто что-то делает с cPanel...